# Smashing the stack example3.c confusion

Tags: c, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, disassembly

Article can be found [here](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html).

I'm reading up on smashing the stack and have found myself to be getting stuck on example3.c.

```
0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp
0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
```

The author indicates that we want to skip from `0x80004a8` to `0x80004b2` and that this jump is 8 bytes; how has the author determined this is 8 bytes? I have recreated the code and sent it through `objdump` and found that it's not 8 bytes (I am on a 64 bit machine but I've made sure to compile using 32 bit):

```
8048452:    e8 b5 ff ff ff          call   804840c <function>
8048457:    c7 44 24 1c 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x1c(%esp)
804845e:    00 
804845f:    8b 44 24 1c             mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
8048463:    89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
8048467:    c7 04 24 18 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048518,(%esp)
```

The author also said "*How did we know to add 8 to the return address?  We used a
test value first (for example 1)*" Where did he use this test value at?

Comment: Moving to StackOverflow by user request. (+1, good question.)

Comment: If you subtract the addresses just like in that article, you get 10 bytes :) check the links at the end of my answer, the offset is wrong.

Comment: There was an answer saying that it has now been revised.  Here is the latest [revision](https://avicoder.me/2016/02/01/smashsatck-revived/)

Answer (score 3):

That's not how I interpret the article. The way I understand it he wants to modify the return address so that the `x = 1;` assignment is skipped, i.e. he wants `function` to return to where the `printf` would be executed.

As you can see in your disassembly, the assignment is 8 bytes (`c7 44 24 1c 01 00 00 00`), hence moving the return address 8 bytes forward would move it past this instruction. As for the "We used a test value first" comment.. maybe he just means that he looked at the code in a disassembler to figure out the length, or that he experimented with different offsets(?).

Answer (score 1):

The displacement in the article is wrong, it should be `10` bytes. When a function is called (or a jump is executed), the return address is set to equal the instruction pointer + the current instruction size:

```
ret = IP + Curr_Inst_size
```

So when the call to the function returns, the instruction pointer should equal `0x80004a8` (`0x80004a3` + the call instruction size):

```
    0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
--> 0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp            
    0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
    0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
```

However, you want to set the instruction pointer to `0x80004b2` instead, *to skip the assignment*, you also, inevitably, have to skip another instruction `(addl $0xc,%esp)` to get there, or in other words, you need to add `(0x80004b2-0x80004a8)` bytes, or 10 bytes, to the instruction pointer to skip those two instructions:

```
    0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
    0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp            
    0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
--> 0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
```

The actual instruction size depends on the operands, machine type etc.. But in this example, the `addl` is 3 bytes long, and the `movl` is 7 bytes long. You could check the [x86 Instruction Set Reference](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410/doc/intel-isr.pdf) for the exact instruction size, or you could compile and disassemble this code, you will see that those two instructions are 10 bytes long:

```
int main()
{
    asm("addl  $0xc,%esp\n\
         movl  $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)");

}
```

gdb:

```
0x08048397 <+3>: 83 c4 0c               add    $0xc,%esp
0x0804839a <+6>: c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00   movl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
```

There's also a discussion [here](http://seclists.org/basics/2005/Oct/87) and [here](http://seclists.org/pen-test/2002/Jul/146) about this exact same issue in example 3.